# Remove "Chapter x:" for starred chapters in heading

Tags: header-footer, pagestyle

I am currently working on a thesis, using a provided class file. In this class file the headers are defined with the following code:

```
% Page geometry and spacing (same for even and odd pages)
\geometry{left=4cm, right=4cm, top=4cm, bottom=4.5cm}
\frenchspacing

% Roman page numbers from the beginning of the document
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

% Switch to Arabic page numbering at the beginning of the first numbered chapter
\newif\iffirstchapter
\firstchaptertrue
\let\std@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter{
    \iffirstchapter
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \firstchapterfalse
    \fi
    \std@chapter
}

% Add unnumbered chapters to table of contents and headings
\let\std@schapter\@schapter
\def\@schapter#1{
    \std@schapter{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \def\ch@ptermark{#1}
}

% Dotted line and tighter vertical spacing for chapters in the table of contents
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.5em}{\bf #1}{\bf #2}}

% Support for included papers (for compiled PhD theses)
\newcounter{paper}
\setcounter{paper}{0}
\def\thepaper{\Roman{paper}}
\newenvironment{paper}[2]
{
    \refstepcounter{paper}
    \def\include@papername{#1}
    \chapter*{\papername~\thepaper}
    \label[paper]{#2}
}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \includepdf[pages=-]{\include@papername}
}

% Allow for two versions of title and authors – full and short
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}\def\@shorttitle{#1}}
\def\shorttitle#1{\def\@shorttitle{#1}}
\def\author#1{\def\@author{#1}\def\@shortauthor{#1}}
\def\shortauthor#1{\def\@shortauthor{#1}}

% Headers and footers
\def\ps@customheadings{%
    \let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\small\thepage\hfil\textit{\@shortauthor: \@shorttitle}}
    \def\@oddhead{\small\textit{\ch@ptermark}\hfil\thepage}
    \def\chaptermark##1{\def\ch@ptermark{\chaptername\ \thechapter: ##1}}
}
\pagestyle{customheadings}
```

For the first parts of the thesis (stuff as "Preface" and others) I am using starred chapters, resulting in a "Chapter 0: "-header. Is there a way to re-write the code above such that my header is

```
<Title>
```

for a starred chapter, and

```
Chapter x: <Title>
```

for "normal" chapters? Ideally it should be possible to choose if starred chapters between un-starred chapters increase the chapter counter, or not.

Comment: Please add a compilable example, from `documentclass` to end{document}`.  Also the complete class used or a link to.  In your snippet \std@chapter is not defined and there is a comment about  unnumbered chapters .

Comment: The code as you have given us does what you want. With `\chapter*{Preface}` the header will be just `Preface`, not `Chapter 0: Preface`. So if you don't get this, there must be something else that you are not telling us.